# Wordpress User Export - only export users who *haven't* logged in

Tags: wordpress

I need to do an export of users who only 'haven't' logged in to Wordpress yet - IE they've registered, but not logged in. Is this possible?

I can't see any fields from the database which are specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try the **usermeta table**.

The following fields have the info to help you.

- wc_last_active
- last_update
- eig_last_login
- session_tokens
- show_welcome_panel

Then maybe you can use the PHPmyadmin to do a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'eig_last_login')
```